# Forward, backward etc sexp not working

Tags: motion, keystrokes, prefix-keys, sexp, modifier-key

I want to use the `forward-sexp` function in Emacs, which on my Spacemacs for Mac is bound to `C-M-f`.

Similarly for the `backward-sexp`. However, upon pressing `C-` for Control, and then the Meta key, which is the Escape key, I'm getting the following in the minibuffer:

```
<C-escape> is undefined.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The Meta key is *NOT* the Escape key.

Comment: @NickD
I used to think all along that the escape key was meta key because when I did ```Escape - x```, spacemacs would show ```M - x```. Why is that the case if Escape isn't the meta key?

Comment: `Escape-x` gets translated to `M-x` - current versions of Emacs say `M-x (translated from <escape> x) runs the command execute-extended-command` which should make things a bit clearer. @Drew's answer explains in more depth.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a <kbd>Meta</kbd> key (it is often <kbd>Alt</kbd>) then you can use <kbd>Escape</kbd>, yes.

But in that case, what you want to use is <kbd>Escape</kbd> *followed by* <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, which we write as `ESC C-f`.

That is, Emacs writes the key sequence as `ESC C-f` when it talks to you about it.

A <kbd>Meta</kbd> key, which we write as `M-`, is a **modifier key**, which means you press and *hold it down* while you press the next key.  Same thing for the <kbd>Control</kbd> key, which we write as `C-`: it's also a modifier key. And so is the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

The <kbd>Escape</kbd> key is *not* a modifier key.  It's a **prefix key**.  You press and *release* it, then carry on with the other keys of the key sequence. So you press and *release* <kbd>Escape</kbd>, then you press and *hold down* <kbd>Control</kbd> while you press <kbd>f</kbd>.

See the Emacs manual, node [User Input](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/User-Input.html), and the Elisp manual, nodes [Functions for Key Lookup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Functions-for-Key-Lookup.html) and [Prefix Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html).

Comment: I used to think all along that the escape key was meta key because when I did ```Escape - x```, spacemacs would show ```M - x```. Why is that the case if Escape isn't the meta key?

Comment: See the manual pages I pointed to.